# Validation isn't working for me for a bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Can someone help me find the errors that i have in the fiddle that i shared below. it seems like i am doing something wrong since validation doesn't work for me. I get the following error when i try debugging in chrome

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#createServiceSpace').validate({
            rules: {
                serviceName: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 20,
                    required: true
                },
                serviceOwners: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.controls').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98hoL701/

Comment: Your Fiddle does not include a validation library like http://bootstrapvalidator.com/ or similar

Comment: added but still doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/98hoL701/1/. Sorry for missing that as part of the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/98hoL701/3/

As far as I know validation only works with forms, not divs.

Also you're trying to validate on href click, by default validation works on input submit.

So I added form to your sample and validated the form, also called the validation on href click:

```
$("#aNext").on("click", function(){
    var val = $('#myform').valid();

    if (!val)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Curious can this also help to validate regex pattern?

Comment: Google found a lot of answers for that, i.e. see [this link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for regex and validator.addMethod

Comment: True I already found the solution you mentioned above. But I was looking for something provided by default by jquery validator. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Try $("#form").validate({
 rules: {
    "password": {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}/
    }
 }
});